# how to run multiple postman collections using newman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, newman

I have 10 collections with each one having its own environment files. I am running those using feedfile.json

It is running fine but 2 issues:
1- creating many cloned collection files inside the folder which is confusing every time I have to delete them manually.
2-  It is creating separate html reports but I want a single report for all any help?

Comment: You wouldn't get an aggregated or single report. It's one report per collection.